# Keep receiving "System.ArgumentException" when array count is not even

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I keep receiving the error:

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection

When the count of array elements is not even at `directions.RemoveRange(i, 2);`

```
public static string[] way(String[] arr)
{
    int[] secondaryArr = new int[arr.Length];

    for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
    {
        switch (arr[j])
        {
            case "NORTH":
                secondaryArr[j] = 1;
                break;
            case "SOUTH":
                secondaryArr[j] = -1;
                break;
            case "WEST":
                secondaryArr[j] = 2;
                break;
            case "EAST":
                secondaryArr[j] = -2;
                break;
        }
    }

    var directions = arr.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < directions.Count / 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondaryArr.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (secondaryArr[j] + secondaryArr[j + 1] == 0)
            {
                directions.RemoveRange(i, 2);
                i = 0;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    arr = directions.ToArray();
    return arr;
}
```

I need to reduce the directions when the route is not reasonable. For example when I receive input like: `[NORTH],[SOUTH],[WEST]`, it should be reduced to: `[WEST]`, because going `NORTH` and `SOUTH` is not reasonable. The problem is that I get stuck at sorting the array.

Comment: Your title says you get the error when it's not even, but then you say you get the error when it *is* even in your question. Which is it?

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the collection as you are iterating over it. Maybe if you said more about how you need to solve the problem we could help come up with a more reasonable solution.

Comment: Your code seems to work, although I took the liberty of changing your input to an array of strings rather than an array of arrays of strings like it appears you're using (`[NORTH],[SOUTH],[WEST]`): https://dotnetfiddle.net/bWW1Xu

Comment: Mistype at "count is even at" should be "count is not even at"

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your code and see what's going on. You can set a breakpoint at `RemoveRange` and check the value of `i` as well as `directions.Count`. In general, removing items from an array while you're iterating over it can be problematic. Normally when doing this, you would walk *backwards* through the array so you never have any index issues (whereas you're walking forward and then resetting the counters when you remove something).

Comment: One problem is definitively setting `i = 0;` and `j = 0;` from within the loop. Because when you do that, you must be aware, you are probably not exiting the inner loop, but just "restarting" it. But before that `j`is incremented because of the `j++`. Furthermore, once you leave the inner loop and `i` was set to `0` it's incremented, because of the `i++` of the outer loop. Probably that's not realy what you want.